# How to access a slice of packed_bits<> as a std::bitset<>?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bit-manipulation, variadic-templates

I am attempting to implement a `packed_bits` class using variadic templates and `std::bitset`.

In particular, I am running into problems writing a `get` function which returns a reference to a subset of the member `m_bits` which contains all the packed bits.  The function should be analogous to `std::get` for `std::tuple`.

It should act as an *reference overlay* so I can manipulate a subset of `packed_bits`.

For instance,

```
using my_bits = packed_bits<8,16,4>;
my_bits b;
std::bitset<  8 >& s0 = get<0>( b );
std::bitset< 16 >& s1 = get<1>( b );
std::bitset<  4 >& s2 = get<2>( b );
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the code that has been rewritten according to [Yakk's recommendations below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906694/975129).  I am stuck at the point of his last paragraph: not sure how to *glue together* the individual references into one *bitset-like* reference.  Thinking/working on that last part now.

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, my new approach is going to be to let `bit_slice<>` do the bulk of the work:

- it is meant to be short-lived
- it will publicly subclass `std::bitset<length>`, acting as a temporary buffer
- on construction, it will copy from `packed_bits<>& m_parent;`
- on destruction, it will write to `m_parent`
- in addition to the reference via `m_parent`, it must also know offset, length
- `get<>` will become a free-function which takes a `packet_bits<>` and returns a `bit_slice<>` by value instead of `bitset<>` by reference

There are various short-comings to this approach:

- `bit_slice<>` has to be relatively short-lived to avoid aliasing issues, since we only update on construction and destruction
- we must avoid multiple overlapping references while coding (whether threaded or not)
- we will be prone to slicing if we attempt to hold a pointer to the base class when we have an instance of the child class

but I think this will be sufficient for my needs.  I will post the finished code when it is complete.

**UPDATE 3**

After fighting with the compiler, I think I have a basic version working.  Unfortunately, I could not get the free-floating `::get()` to compile properly:  `BROKEN` shows the spot.  Otherwise, I think it's working.

*Many thanks to Yakk for his suggestions: the code below is about 90%+ based on his comments.*

**UPDATE 4**

Free-floating `::get()` fixed.

**UPDATE 5**

As suggested by Yakk, I have eliminated the copy.  `bit_slice<>` will read on `get_value()` and write on `set_value()`.  Probably 90%+ of my calls will be through these interfaces anyways, so no need to subclass/copy.

No more dirtiness.

**CODE**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<unsigned... Args>
struct Add { enum { val = 0 }; };

template<unsigned I,unsigned... Args>
struct Add<I,Args...> { enum { val = I + Add<Args...>::val }; };

template<int IDX,unsigned... Args>
struct Offset { enum { val = 0 }; };

template<int IDX,unsigned I,unsigned... Args>
struct Offset<IDX,I,Args...> { 
    enum { 
        val = IDX>0 ? I + Offset<IDX-1,Args...>::val : Offset<IDX-1,Args...>::val 
    }; 
};

template<int IDX,unsigned... Args>
struct Length { enum { val = 0 }; };

template<int IDX,unsigned I,unsigned... Args>
struct Length<IDX,I,Args...> { 
    enum { 
        val = IDX==0 ? I : Length<IDX-1,Args...>::val 
    }; 
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<unsigned... N_Bits>
struct seq
{
    static const unsigned total_bits = Add<N_Bits...>::val;
    static const unsigned size       = sizeof...( N_Bits );

    template<int IDX>
    struct offset
    {
        enum { val = Offset<IDX,N_Bits...>::val };
    };

    template<int IDX>
    struct length
    {
        enum { val = Length<IDX,N_Bits...>::val };
    };
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<unsigned offset,unsigned length,typename PACKED_BITS>
struct bit_slice
{
    PACKED_BITS& m_parent;

    bit_slice( PACKED_BITS& t ) :
        m_parent( t )
    { 
    }

    ~bit_slice()
    {
    }

    bit_slice( bit_slice const& rhs ) :
        m_parent( rhs.m_parent )
    { }

    bit_slice& operator=( bit_slice const& rhs ) = delete;

    template<typename U_TYPE>
    void set_value( U_TYPE u )
    {
        for ( unsigned i=0; i<length; ++i )
        {
            m_parent[offset+i] = u&1;
            u >>= 1;
        }
    }

    template<typename U_TYPE>
    U_TYPE get_value() const
    {
        U_TYPE x = 0;
        for ( int i=length-1; i>=0; --i )
        {
            if ( m_parent[offset+i] )
                ++x;
            if ( i!=0 )
                x <<= 1;
        }
        return x;
    }
};

template<typename SEQ>
struct packed_bits :
    public std::bitset< SEQ::total_bits >
{  
    using bs_type   = std::bitset< SEQ::total_bits >;
    using reference = typename bs_type::reference;

    template<int IDX> using offset = typename SEQ::template offset<IDX>;
    template<int IDX> using length = typename SEQ::template length<IDX>;
    template<int IDX> using slice_type = 
        bit_slice<offset<IDX>::val,length<IDX>::val,packed_bits>;

    template<int IDX>
    slice_type<IDX> get()
    {
        return slice_type<IDX>( *this );
    }
};

template<int IDX,typename T>
typename T::template slice_type<IDX>
get( T& t )
{
    return t.get<IDX>();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    using my_seq   = seq<8,16,4,8,4>;
    using my_bits  = packed_bits<my_seq>;
    using my_slice = bit_slice<8,16,my_bits>;
    using slice_1  = 
        bit_slice<my_bits::offset<1>::val,my_bits::length<1>::val,my_bits>;

    my_bits        b;
    my_slice       s(  b );
    slice_1        s1( b );

    assert( sizeof( b )==8 );
    assert( my_seq::total_bits==40 );
    assert( my_seq::size==5 );

    assert( my_seq::offset<0>::val==0  );
    assert( my_seq::offset<1>::val==8  );
    assert( my_seq::offset<2>::val==24 );
    assert( my_seq::offset<3>::val==28 );
    assert( my_seq::offset<4>::val==36 );

    assert( my_seq::length<0>::val==8  );
    assert( my_seq::length<1>::val==16 );
    assert( my_seq::length<2>::val==4  );
    assert( my_seq::length<3>::val==8  );
    assert( my_seq::length<4>::val==4  );

    {
        auto s2 = b.get<2>();
    }
    {
        auto s2 = ::get<2>( b );
        s2.set_value( 25 );  // 25==11001, but only 4 bits, so we take 1001 
        assert( s2.get_value<unsigned>()==9 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have `get` return a `bitset`, because each `bitset` needs to manage its own memory.

Instead, I'd use a `bitset` internally to manage all of the bits, and create `bitset::reference`-like individual bit references, and `bitset`-like "slices", which `get` can return.

A `bitslice` would have a pointer back to the original `packed_bits`, and would know the offset where it starts, and how wide it is.  It's `references` to individual bits would be `references` from the original `packed_bits`, which are `references` from the internal `bitset`, possibly.

Your `Size` is redundant -- `sizeof...(pack)` tells you how many elements are in the pack.

I'd pack up the sizes of the slices into a seqence so you can pass it around easier.  Ie:

```
template<unsigned... Vs>
struct seq {};
```

is a type from which you can extract an arbitrary length list of `unsigned int`s, yet can be passed as a single parameter to a template.

As a first step, write `bit_slice<offset, length>`, which takes a `std::bitset<size>` and produces `bitset::reference`s to individual bits, where `bit_slice<offset, length>[n]` is the same as `bitset[n+offset]`.

Optionally, `bit_slice` could store `offset` as a run-time parameter (because `offset` as a compile-time parameter is just an optimization, and not that strong of one I suspect).

Once you have `bit_slice`, working on the tuple syntax of `packed_bits` is feasible.  `get<n, offset=0>( packed_bits<a,b,c,...>& )` returns a `bit_slice<x>` determined by indexing the `packed_bits` sizes, with an `offset` determined by adding the first n-1 `packed_bits` sizes, which is then constructed from the internal `bitset` of the `packed_bits`.

Make sense?

Apparently not.  Here is a quick `bit_slice` that represents some sub-range of bits within a `std::bitset`.

```
#include <bitset>

template<unsigned Width, unsigned Offset, std::size_t SrcBitWidth>
struct bit_slice {
private:
  std::bitset<SrcBitWidth>* bits;
public:
  // cast to `bitset`:
  operator std::bitset<Width>() const {
    std::bitset<Width> retval;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < Offset; ++i) {
      retval[i] = (*this)[i];
    }
    return retval;
  }
  typedef typename std::bitset<SrcBitWidth>::reference reference;
  reference operator[]( size_t pos ) {
    // TODO: check that pos < Width?
    return (*bits)[pos+Offset];
  }
  constexpr bool operator[]( size_t pos ) const {
    // TODO: check that pos < Width?
    return (*bits)[pos+Offset];
  }
  typedef bit_slice<Width, Offset, SrcBitWidth> self_type;
  // can be assigned to from any bit_slice with the same width:
  template<unsigned O_Offset, unsigned O_SrcBitWidth>
  self_type& operator=( bit_slice<Width, O_Offset, O_SrcBitWidth>&& o ) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Width; ++i ) {
      (*this)[i] = o[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }
  // can be assigned from a `std::bitset<Width>` of the same size:
  self_type& operator=( std::bitset<Width> const& o ) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Width; ++i ) {
      (*this)[i] = o[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }
  explicit bit_slice( std::bitset<SrcBitWidth>& src ):bits(&src) {}
  bit_slice( self_type const& ) = default;
  bit_slice( self_type&& ) = default;
  bit_slice( self_type&o ):bit_slice( const_cast<self_type const&>(o)) {}
  // I suspect, but am not certain, the the default move/copy ctor would do...
  // dtor not needed, as there is nothing to destroy

  // TODO: reimplement rest of std::bitset's interface that you care about
};

template<unsigned offset, unsigned width, std::size_t src_width>
bit_slice< width, offset, src_width > make_slice( std::bitset<src_width>& src ) {
  return bit_slice< width, offset, src_width >(src);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::bitset<16> bits;
  bits[8] = true;
  auto slice = make_slice< 8, 8 >( bits );
  bool b0 = slice[0];
  bool b1 = slice[1];
  std::cout << b0 << b1 << "\n"; // should output 10
}
```

Another useful class would be a `bit_slice` with runtime offset-and-source size.  This will be less efficient, but easier to program against.

Comment: ok - I've implemented everything according to your recommendations. I'm just stuck on that last paragraph:  I'm not sure how I can *glue together* the individual `bitset<>::reference` into some kind of `bitset<>&` - thinking about that now.

Comment: @kfmfe04 So you have a `bit_slice` that can extract a range of bits from a `bitset` and expose an `operator[]` view of it?  It is less constructing the `bitset` out of `reference` than extracting slices of reference from a `bitset`.

Comment: Yes, because `bit_slice` derives from `std::bitset<>`, I will have access to all the functionality that is in `bit::bitset<>`.  By bifurcating the data (making a copy), I will use more space + there are other aliasing dangers, but it will be ok if I'm careful.  The problem with just grabbing `bitset::reference` is that one-bit-at-a-time is not as convenient as a bunch of bits at once.  For my purposes, I am stuffing several `std::bitset<>` representing multiple-indexes that I use as a compact key.  When manipulating slices, viewing them as unsigned short, for example, is quite convenient.

Comment: btw, what do you mean by `It is less constructing the bitset out of reference than extracting slices of reference from a bitset`?  I might be able to improve the code with your insight.

Comment: No, you cannot derive.  Derivation is the wrong thing to do.  Stop deriving.  You want exactly one `bitset`, and that is one owned by `packed_bits` for storage.  You should not make a copy: that makes writing ugly.

Comment: TY again for the cleanliness-enforcement: *I appreciate your looking-over-my-shoulder*.  I have expunged the extra copy and the subclassing in `bit_slice<>`.

Comment: @kfmfe04 see above for a `bit_slice` implementation that is half done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess it something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

template<int N, int L, int R>
bitset<L-R>
slice(bitset<N> value)
{
    size_t W = L - R + 1;
    if (W > sizeof(uint64_t) * 8) {
        W = 31;
        throw("Exceeding integer word size");
    }

    uint64_t svalue = (value.to_ulong() >> R) & ((1 << W) - 1);

        return bitset<L-R>{svalue};
    }
}

int main()
{
    bitset<16>  beef { 0xBEEF };
    bitset<4-3> sliced_beef      = slice<16, 4, 3>(beef);    
    auto        fast_sliced_beef = slice<16, 4, 3>(beef);
    return 0;
}
```